# How to display a error in a div if password is too short or too long using JavaScript or PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

How do you display a error depending on the length of the text inputted to a password field. For example if a user inputted 18 characters but the limit was 16 the JavaScript or PHP would display "Limit is 16 characters" in a div. Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Project</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <span class="main_text">Textbox</span><br>
    <input name="textbox1" type="password" id="textbox1" placeholder="Password"><br>
    // Display error here
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks, Omar.

Ps, Here is a example of what I mean:
[image: This is a example]

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself ?

Comment: despite that isn't what you want, you can add `maxlength` property in your `input` tag. `<input name="textbox1" type="password" id="textbox1" placeholder="password" maxlength="16" />`;

Comment: No, I don't have a clue how to do this and I couldn't find anything on the topic. I'm a beginner.

Comment: Why would you limit the length of a password field?

Answer (score 0):

add `onchange='checkPasswordLength(this.value)'` to the `input`'s opening tag.

Then, after the input, add:

```
<span id="errorSpan" style="color:red;"></span>
<script>
    function checkPasswordLength(password){
         if (password.length > 16) {
             document.getElementById("errorSpan").innerHTML = "Limit is 16 characters";
         }
         else {
             document.getElementById("errorSpan").innerHTML = "";
         } 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Just to be clear, a malicious user can bypass any front-end JavaScript code enforcing rules on a password simply by disabling JavaScript in their browser. Front end rules are good, but make sure they're replicated on the back-end as well.

Answer (score 0):

there are server-side ways and client-side ways.  First check will be client side.  I do it like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <span class="main_text">Textbox</span><br>
    <input name="textbox1" type="password" id="textbox1" placeholder="Password" 
           onKeyup='checkLength()'>
    <br>
    // Display error here
    <span id="errorSpan"></span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkLength(){
        var tb = document.getElementById('textbox1');
        var limit = 16;  // set this?
        if(tb.length > limit){
            document.getElementById('errorSpan').innerHtml ='This field is limited to '+ limit +' characters';
            // leave only the first 'limit' chars in the field...
            tb.innerHtml = tb.innerHtml.substr(0,limit);
        }else{
            document.getElementById('errorSpan').innerHtml = '';
        }
    }
</script>
```

you can make it slightly more reusable like:

```
<div class="container">
    <span class="main_text">Textbox</span><br>
    <input name="textbox1" type="password" id="textbox1" placeholder="Password" 
           onKeyup='checkLength(this,16,'errorSpan')'>
    <br>
    // Display error here
    <span id="errorSpan"></span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkLength(field, limit, showWhere){
        var tb = field;
        if(tb.length > limit){
            document.getElementById(showWhere).innerHtml ='This field is limited to '+ limit +' characters';
            // leave only the first 'limit' chars in the field...
            tb.innerHtml = tb.innerHtml.substr(0,limit);
        }else{
            document.getElementById(showWhere).innerHtml = '';
        }
    }
</script>
```

hope that is enough to get you started.  You should also do a server-side check because people can bypass javascript pretty easily.

Answer (score -1):

Check this code for example - http://codepen.io/shhade/pen/nBmJy

Comment: Thanks, But is there a way to display the text as the user is typing?

Comment: Just replace the focusout event to keypress event see my changes in the link

Comment: It works on CodePen but when I put it into my website it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

```
var textbox1 = document.getElementById('textbox1');
function checkLength() {
    var length = textbox1.length;
    if (length > 16) {textbox1.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', 'You are limited to 16 characters');}
}
textbox1.addEventListener('change', checkLength, false);
```

While you could also use the `.innerHTML` method, `.insertAdjacentHTML` gives you control over where you want to insert the string. It also provides a *significant* performance boost.
https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/11/insertadjacenthtml-enables-faster-html-snippet-injection/

EDIT: You could also listen for any of the key events. i.e keypress, keyup, keydown.
Also, I should point out you shouldn't rely on JavaScript for things like this. JavaScript can be disabled. Have something implemented server-side.

Answer (score -1):

you can use the `strlen()` in `php`. the `strlen()` functions counts the number of character that are in a string.

```
<?php
if(strlen($password) < 6) {
    echo 'ERROR: password is too short';
} 
else {
    echo 'Congratulations! Your password is secured';
}
?>
```